# how can I make a numpy function that accepts a numpy array, an iterable, or a scalar?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have this:

```
def incrementElements(x):
   return x+1
```

but I want to modify it so that it can take either a numpy array, an iterable, or a scalar, and promote the argument to a numpy array and add 1 to each element.

How could I do that? I suppose I could test argument class but that seems like a bad idea. If I do this:

```
def incrementElements(x):
   return numpy.array(x)+1
```

it works properly on arrays or iterables but not scalars. The problem here is that `numpy.array(x)` for scalar x produces some weird object that is contained by a numpy array but isn't a "real" array; if I add a scalar to it, the result is demoted to a scalar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try

```
def incrementElements(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    return x+1
```

`np.asarray(x)` is the equivalent of `np.array(x, copy=False)`, meaning that a scalar or an iterable will be transformed to a `ndarray`, but if `x` is already a `ndarray`, its data will not be copied.

If you pass a scalar and want a `ndarray` as output (not a scalar), you can use:

```
def incrementElements(x):
    x = np.array(x, copy=False, ndmin=1)
    return x
```

The `ndmin=1` argument will force the array to have at least one dimension. Use `ndmin=2` for at least 2 dimensions, and so forth. You can also use its equivalent `np.atleast_1d` (or `np.atleast_2d` for the 2D version...)

Comment: That looks like it behaves essentially like numpy.array(). The problem with this is that `np.array(3)` behaves differently than `np.array([3])`

Comment: I need to promote scalars to a list somehow.

Comment: @JasonS: you could use `vectorize` -- i.e. `newfn = np.vectorize(incrementElements)` which would work on arrays, lists, *and* scalars, but it won't work on things like genexps, which are iterable too... ah, I seem from your update you want to avoid 0-dimensional arrays, so that won't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Pierre GM's answer is great so long as your function exclusively uses ufuncs (or something similar) to implicitly loop over the input values. If your function needs to *iterate* over the inputs, then `np.asarray` doesn't do enough, because you can't iterate over a NumPy scalar:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.asarray(1)
for xval in x:
    print(np.exp(xval))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 2.py", line 4, in <module>
    for xval in x:
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

If your function needs to iterate over the input, something like the following will work, using `np.atleast_1d`  and `np.squeeze` (see [Array manipulation routines — NumPy Manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html)). I included an `aaout` ("Always Array OUT") arg so you can specify whether you want scalar inputs to produce single-element array outputs; it could be dropped if not needed:

```
def scalar_or_iter_in(x, aaout=False):
    """
    Gather function evaluations over scalar or iterable `x` values.

    aaout :: boolean
        "Always array output" flag:  If True, scalar input produces
        a 1-D, single-element array output.  If false, scalar input
        produces scalar output.
    """
    x = np.asarray(x)
    scalar_in = x.ndim==0

    # Could use np.array instead of np.atleast_1d, as follows:
    # xvals = np.array(x, copy=False, ndmin=1)
    xvals = np.atleast_1d(x)
    y = np.empty_like(xvals, dtype=float)  # dtype in case input is ints
    for i, xx in enumerate(xvals):
        y[i] = np.exp(xx)  # YOUR OPERATIONS HERE!

    if scalar_in and not aaout:
        return np.squeeze(y)
    else:
        return y


print(scalar_or_iter_in(1.))
print(scalar_or_iter_in(1., aaout=True))
print(scalar_or_iter_in([1,2,3]))


2.718281828459045
[2.71828183]
[ 2.71828183  7.3890561  20.08553692]
```

Of course, for exponentiation you should not explicitly iterate as here, but a more complex operation may not be expressible using NumPy ufuncs.  If you do *not* need to iterate, but want similar control over whether scalar inputs produce single-element array outputs, the middle of the function could be simpler, but the return has to handle the `np.atleast_1d`:

```
def scalar_or_iter_in(x, aaout=False):
    """
    Gather function evaluations over scalar or iterable `x` values.

    aaout :: boolean
        "Always array output" flag:  If True, scalar input produces
        a 1-D, single-element array output.  If false, scalar input
        produces scalar output.
    """
    x = np.asarray(x)
    scalar_in = x.ndim==0

    y = np.exp(x)  # YOUR OPERATIONS HERE!

    if scalar_in and not aaout:
        return np.squeeze(y)
    else:
        return np.atleast_1d(y)
```

I suspect in most cases the `aaout` flag is not necessary, and that you'd always want scalar outputs with scalar inputs.  In such cases, the return should just be:

```
    if scalar_in:
        return np.squeeze(y)
    else:
        return y
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but here are my two cents.

Although Pierre GM's answer works great, it has the---maybe undesirable---side effect of converting scalars to arrays. If that is what you want/need, then stop reading; otherwise, carry on. While this might be okay (and is probably good for `lists` and other `iterables` to return a `np.array`), it could be argued that for scalars it should return a scalar. If that's the desired behaviour, why not follow python's [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) philosophy. This is what I usually do (I changed the example to show what could happen when `np.asarray` returns a "scalar"):

```
def saturateElements(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    try:
        x[x>1] = 1
    except TypeError:
        x = min(x,1)
    return x
```

I realize it is more verbose than Pierre GM's answer, but as I said, this solution will return a scalar if a scalar is passed, or a `np.array` is an array or iterable is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Existing solutions all work. Here's yet another option.

```
def incrementElements(x):
    try:
        iter(x)
    except TypeError:
        x = [x]
    x = np.array(x)
    # code that operators on x
```

Comment: [`numpy.atleast_1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html) would be more appropriate